# Graphing empty input boxes using TChart

Tags: delphi

I'm getting the user to enter coefficients (as strings) for terms from a constant (e.g. 2) all the way up to a sextic (e.g. 3X^6).

The user enters each coefficient without the X-term attached to it, so 3X^6 is entered just as 3.

Upon clicking an okay button, the idea is to transfer the coefficients which are valid (checked using a RegEx expression) to a procedure ('CreateGraph') which actually creates the graph using TChart.

Upon clicking the okay button, a loop for i = 1 to 7 (number of coefficients) is used to check if each term is valid. The issue I am having is that I get a string conversion error when converting the coefficients in the CreateGraph procedure as the other coefficients except those with data in, are set to '', which TChart won't accept.

Here's the current procedure:

```
procedure TfrmGetFunction.btnAddFunctionClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
  i : integer; // Loop counter.
 begin
  for i := 1 to 7 do
   begin
    if CheckCoefficientBoxesValidInput(CoefficientEdit[i].CoEditBox) then
      frmGraphingMode.CreateGraph(CoefficientEdit[i].CoEditBox);
   end;
 end;
```

Is the best way to just set the inactive coefficient edit boxes to '0'?

The (potential) issue I have with that is that when the user wants to enter another set of coefficients or comes back to the 'Enter Function' form, the values are all set to 0 which may be confusing.

The next issue (related to the first) that I am having, is that the CreateGraph procedure is called each time i is incremented, which means that a load of empty input boxes are passed, which TChart doesn't like.

Here's my current procedure:

```
  var
   i : integer; // Loop counter.
   Coeff : array[1..7] of string;
  begin
   for i := 1 to 7 do
    begin
     Coeff[i] := CoefficientEdit[i].CoEditBox.Text;
     if Coeff[i] = '' then
      Coeff[i] := '0';
     frmGraphingMode.CreateGraph(Coeff[i]);
    end;
  end;
```

What is the easiest way to solve this problem? I was thinking of having a boolean variable which is set to true when the loop is complete (i.e. i = 7 is when all the empty (if so) boxes would be filled in); is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check for the empty string and replace with `'0'`.

```
var
  Coeff: string;
....
Coeff := CoefficientEdit[i].CoEditBox.Text;
if Coeff = '' then
  Coeff := '0';
```

I'm assuming that `CoEditBox` is an edit control. If so then I would comment that you should not pass an edit control to `CheckCoefficientBoxesValidInput` and `CreateGraph`. Those functions should receive string arguments. You are making them needlessly coupled to a particular GUI design.

Perhaps this is the root cause of your problems. You comment that it is confusing for the edit controls to be changed to contain zeros. Well, you don't need to, and should now, change the edit controls. Separate the GUI from the charting. Don't pass around edit controls. Pull the contents from the controls, optionally process it, and pass it on.

Finally, instead of using a regex to check if a value is a number, call `TryStrToFloat`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it okay to read each edit control's text input field into an array of string, so you have an array for the edit control itself and an array for the output as a string, hence separate from the edit controls?

Comment: That sounds quite reasonable yes. Then the code that plots can work with input from sources other than your GUI should that ever be needed.

Comment: The issue is that the text taken from said edit boxes is blank until the loop gets to their respective part of the array. Until then, they are blank which causes TChart to error.

Comment: No, the issue is that you asked a question which was answered but you seem to expect something else.

Comment: What is your suggestion then? Start a new thread? Close this one? I'm seeing lots of insults but few suggestions.

Comment: You asked how to detect and deal with empty fields by treating them as zero. That was the question you asked. I can't see any insults.

Comment: What about this one though? And your other one?

Comment: Your logic dictates that this thread is answered, so it is worth closing it/not responding to it anymore, no?

Comment: Only you can accept an answer. Do so only if you feel the question you asked was well answered.